# readQuery from cache results in Can't find field <field> on object undefined

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm getting started with graphQL and apollo. I'm doing some simple queries and mutations fine but when I try to access data from apollo cache I keep getting "Can't find field me on object undefined" but when using apollo chrome plugin it returns data correct.

When logged into my app I run a simple query that fetches the user object from the server. It logs correct, I can see in chome dev apollo under queries and cache that my user data is there.

```
const ME_QUERY = gql`
query {
    me {
    _id
    username
    password
    exchanges {
        name
        active
        }
    }
}
`;

<Query query={ME_QUERY}>
  {({loading, error, data}) => {
    if (error) {
      return <Error error={error.message} />;
    }
    if (data) {
      console.log(data, 'data');
    }
    return <div>asdf</div>
  }}
</Query>
```

I have wrapped withApollo and I can log the client object fine in the component where I'm trying to query. I run the following code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.client.readQuery, 'propps');
    const  user = this.props.client.readQuery({
        query: gql`
{
  me {
    _id
    username
    password
    exchanges {
      name
      active
    }
  }
}
      `
});
console.log(user, 'user');
```

And that results in Uncaught Error: Can't find field me on object undefined Ive also tried with adding variables but it doesn't help.

Which object is undefined? Any idea why my query fails?

Comment: Does adding word `query` to the query in readQuery fix the problem?

Comment: Did you find a soln?

Answer (score -3):

You are probably using Apollo Client > 2.5 which handles state locally. 
Read the [migration guide](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state#migrating) for more information.

- Use the default client `resolver` to resolve your local state
- Use `cache.write` to write default data into your cache. This is the part of the migration that causes your crash.

Comment: You might want to comment on why you think this answer is bad. I had this very same problem and I solved it this way.

Comment: I'm using Apollo Client 2.6.8